# i'm writing data to xml file by creating folder and file if not exists in clr stored procedure in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, io, permissions, sqlclr

I'm trying this;

```
public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void ExportXML_v1_2(string file_path, string file_name, string xml_data, out int status, out string error_messages)
    {
        string Folder1 = file_path;
        string xml = xml_data;
        error_messages = "";
        status = 0;
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Folder1))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Folder1);
            }
```

I get this error;

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.    at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object
>   demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)    at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()    at
>   System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean
>   checkHost)    at StoredProcedures.ExportXML_v1_2(String file_path,
>   String file_name, String xml_data, Int32& status, String&
>   error_messages)
>
> The action that failed was: Demand The type of the first permission
>   that failed was: System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission
>   The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer

Comment: Is it a webApp?

Comment: no, sql server clr stored procedure

Comment: did  u check https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/58b01172-1487-46a9-88bc-bd0970782d1d/accessing-io-resources-from-clr-stored-procedure?forum=sqlnetfx

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark the Assembly as `WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS`. And, in order to do that you need to:

1. Sign the assembly
2. Create an Asymmetric Key in master
3. Create a login from that asymmetric key
4. Grant that login the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` permission

Of course, there are some variations on how you might go about this, depending on if you are using Visual Studio / SSDT, especially in light of recent changes introduced in SQL Server 2017. For details, please see two blog posts that I have written detailing two methods of accomplishing this, fully automated within Visual Studio, and working within the new "clr strict security" constraint of SQL Server 2017:

- [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 2: “CLR strict security” – Solution 1](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/09/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-2-clr-strict-security-solution-1/)
- [SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 3: “CLR strict security” – Solution 2](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/16/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-3-clr-strict-security-solution-2/)

Also, you should not be using the `string` type as an input / output parameter type when working with SQLCLR. You should use the appropriate `Sql*` types, and in this case that would be `SqlString`. Then, you get the actual string value via the `Value` property. And, for the `xml_data` parameter, use the `SqlXml` type as you can create an `XmlReader` from it which should not only be slightly faster, but it will also allow for better handling of changing the encoding (to UTF-8 most likely) as well as proper handling of the `<?xml ... ?>` declaration at the top. For example:

```cs
public static void ExportXML_v1_2(SqlString file_path, SqlString file_name,
   SqlXml xml_data, out int status, out SqlString error_messages)
{
    if (file_path.IsNull)
    {
       error_messages = "@file_path cannot be NULL.";
       return;
    }

    string Folder1 = file_path.Value;
```

For more information on working with SQLCLR in General, please see the series that I am writing on this topic on SQL Server Central: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) (especially Level 5).

And, FWIW, a function that saves XML to a file, handles formatting (e.g. indenting, etc), append vs overwrite, and encoding (including specifying it in the `<?xml ... ?>` declaration) is available in [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_46876989) (which I wrote). The function is **XML_SaveToFile**, and while many functions are available in the Free version, this particular function is only available in the Full (i.e. paid for) version.

Comment: Is it just best practice to use the `Sql*` types or is there generally a performance gain that you have seen?

Comment: @thomas Functionality more than performance. Initially part of it was built-in support for `NULL` handling before nullable types existed. But also there are properties and methods of those types that are lost when using the native .NET types, especially `string`: `SqlString` can get you the `VARCHAR` bytes and LCID and comparison style; `SqlChars` doesn't send any data over until first access (can be handy if there is a large value that might not be used for some reason). Also, these are the types the system is using for the SQLCLR API. They implicitly convert, but best to use what's intended.